# Linear Algebra: A matrix vs a determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, determinant

I would like to clarify something in regards to finding a determinant of a matrix. For example say I have this problem where I have to evaluate the determinant:

[image]

Is the determinant notation simply a reference to the notion that you are supposed to find the determinant?(as in an operation) So in other words, could I write this matrix with bracket notation if I wanted to? (or if there were no instructions, say)

Comment: Yes: $$\det\left(\begin{array}{ccr}1&7&-3\\1&3&1\\4&8&1\end{array}\right)\quad\text{and}\quad\left|\begin{array}{ccr}1&7&-3\\1&3&1\\4&8&1\end{array}\right|$$mean the same thing; so if the instructions are to "evaluate", then you are to evaluate the determinant of the matrix.

Comment: So I can use bracket (  "[   ]"  ) notation too right?

Comment: I think the convention is that $||$ is used for the determinant of the matrix, and $()$ or $[]$ for the matrix itself.

Comment: @Virtuoso: Brackets should *not* be used for determinants, because a lot of books use them for matrices/vectors. Vertical bars are the standard for determinants.

Comment: @Arturo: do you mind if I ask what the {ccr} means in your code for the matrix (etc) above?

Comment: @amWhy: When declaring an array, you can then declare how you want the columns to be aligned; I declared an array, then said I wanted the first column `c`entered, the second column `c`entered, and the third column `r`ight justified. The other option is `l`, for left-justified. Note I used `\begin{array}`, rather than some of those "newfangled" `\pmatrix` commands that I never learned when I was learning plain TeX.

Comment: @Arturo: Thanks!  I've seen both (\begin{array} and \pmatrix)...thanks for the clarification! (c: center, etc.)

Comment: @Arturo: Please explain about plain TeX. Certainly `\begin{array}` is only LaTeX, but `\pmatrix` is plain TeX and always has been. Maybe it's newfangled in LaTeX, but you should have learnt it when learning plain TeX.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: I seem to have missed the throwaway comment in *The TeX Book* (bottom of page 176); I always assumed `\pmatrix` had been added in LaTeX.

Answer (score 3):

Frequent notations for a matrix are

$\begin{pmatrix}a& b\\ c&d\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}a& b\\ c&d\end{bmatrix}$.

Frequent notations for determinants are

$\left|\begin{matrix}a& b\\ c&d\end{matrix}\right|$ and $\left\|\begin{matrix}a& b\\ c&d\end{matrix}\right\|$ and, of course, 
$\det\begin{pmatrix}a& b\\ c&d\end{pmatrix}$ and $\det\begin{bmatrix}a& b\\ c&d\end{bmatrix}$.

Brackets are sometimes used for determinants if the matrix is given by its row or column vectors, so if $v$ and $w$ are vectors with 2 coordinates then $[v,w]$ might be used for the determinant of the corresponding matrix.

Comment: ...and if we were ever considering the absolute value of a determinant... :D

Comment: Then we take "||" in latex instead of "\|".